# CN1 I18n force a language

Tags: internationalization, codenameone

I'm getting english frases like "done" and "continue" in CN1's built in components.

How may I force those labels to change to spanish? I mean, even if the phone is in english.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this video: https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---localizetranslate-my-application-apply-i18nl10n-internationalizationlocalization-to-my-app.html

You would need to define a resource bundle that includes the Strings "Done" and "Continue" within it and map them to your language. Then install that bundle in the UIManager.

Comment: final UIManager instance = UIManager.getInstance();
        final HashMap<String, String> bundle = new HashMap<>();
        bundle.put("Done", "Aceptar");
        bundle.put("Next", "Siguiente");
        bundle.put("Previous", "Anterior");
        bundle.put("Cancel", "Cancelar");
        bundle.put("CANCEL", "Cancelar");
        bundle.put("OK", "Aceptar");
        bundle.put("NEXT", "Siguiente");
        bundle.put("PREVIOUS", "Anterior");
        instance.setBundle(bundle);

Comment: But on the actual phone, it does not https://postimg.cc/mzDm1M2V/2ca71c1b

Comment: Is this not what was intended? Should I raise a bug?

Comment: This will work everywhere if you use a lightweight picker `Picker.setDefaultUseLightweightPopup(true)`